# What does the name: 'app' line do in this Vue.js CLI code?

Tags: vue.js

What function does the `name: 'app'` have in the following Vue.js CLI code?

I understand that the `export default` is used for

> "creating JavaScript modules to export functions, objects, or
>   primitive values from the module so they can be used by other programs
>   with the import statement" ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export))

and I understand the module to be what is in the `template` element, but I don't see where it is being imported.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Nor do I see what `name: 'app'` does exactly since if I change the name, the Vue.js. code still works, until when you change this in non-CLI Vue.js, e.g.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
});
```

If you change the '#app' then the code won't reference the element and it won't work anymore.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#name

Comment: The gist seems to be that it *the component to recursively invoke itself in its template*, yet I can change the name and it still works. The other advantage seems to be *by providing the name option, you will get a much more informative component tree*. I can even delete it, or for that matter, delete the whole `export default` block and the code still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` Attribute of a Vue component is not really required in projects generated with the vue cli webpack template. In your case, the component name is set elsewhere (since you use vue-router: in `src/router/index.js`), hence it is not technically required in the `export default` of the `*.vue` file.

If you generated your vue cli webpack template without `vue-router` you wouldn't have to supply the component name either, because your `<script>` block would look like this:

```
<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
      ...
      components: {
        Hello
      }
    }
</script>
```

The `components: {Hello}` is a shorthand for `components: {'Hello': Hello}` in EcmaScript 6. This is where the component name would be set in this case.

That being said, setting the component name in the `export default` object of your `*.vue` file is considered good style, because your components will be named consistently across the project and thus be easier to debug. If you changed the `import Hello from ....` to something like `import HelloComponent from ....` it would show up as `HelloComponent` in things like `vue-devtools` and warning messages. You would also now have to reference it as `<hello-component></hello-component>` in your `<template>`. Since you want your component names to be **consistent**, especially when writing components that you intend to be reusable, you should set the `name` property in your vue component once and for all.